# Is there only one natural parametrization per curve?

Tags: calculus, integration, curves, parametrization

Asumming a curve has a natural parametrization (is simple and regular), such natural parametrization is unique or are more parametrizations equivalent to it?

I should add that by natural I mean by arc length, I was taught both terms were equivalent.

Edit:I know parametrizations in general are not unique, the question is if natural parametrizations or by arc length are an exception in that regard.

Comment: The only classification of parameterisations that I know of which is (basically) unique is _parameterisation by arc length_.

Comment: If you fix which point has parameter zero, and you fix which of the two directions is the increasing direction, then is the parameterization by arc length not unique?

Answer (score 2):

No, parametrizations are not unique.

Both
$$t:[0,2\pi],z=e^{it}$$
and
$$t:[-\pi,\pi],z=e^{i(t+\text{any real number})}$$
parametrize a unit circle on the complex plane.

Comment: And there are plenty more!

Comment: What happens if we restrict ourselves to smooth regular (nonvanishing derivative) curves $[a, b] \to \mathbb R^n$?